# Why is the variable undefined? - Node - ElectronJs

Tags: node.js, electron

I am creating an Electron app and I am trying to split my code in different scripts to make it more manageable; however, for some reason one of the variables in my script keeps returning undefined and I can't figure out why. I already checked similar questions here on SO, but did not find an answer.

I have a file called windowManipulation.js and this is part of it:

```
let signInWindow;

module.exports.createSignInWindow = () => {
    signInWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        width: 1500,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    signInWindow.loadFile(`views/logIn.html`)

    signInWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
        signInWindow.show();
    });

    signInWindow.on("close", () => {
        signInWindow = null;
    });

    signInWindow.on('crashed', () => {
        app.relaunch();
        app.exit(0);
    })
}

module.exports.closeSignInWindow = () => {
        signInWindow.close();
        signInWindow = null;
}
```

Now, when I call the function to create the window it creates it without a problem. But when I call the function to close it, it says that signInWindow is undefined.

Why is it undefined if it was supposed to be set when the signInWindow was created? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A class may be better to use here, and have `signInWindow` scoped to the class so both methods are referencing the same variable

Comment: Are you calling `createSignInWindow` and `closeSignInWindow` from the same process (meaning renderer vs main)?

Comment: @AlexWayne I think you hit the nail on the head my man. I just realized that I was calling the closeSignInWindow from the renderer ... But figuring this out now created a different question, but it is related to this question: I have my file windowManipulation.js, how can I execute one of its functions from a renderer? Do I just create a function in the main process that calls the closeSignInWindow function in windowManipulation.js and then I just invoke this function in the main process from the renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `createSignInWindow` and `closeSignInWindow` are being called from different processes. Being different processes, they each their own memory, and each would execute this file independently. So if you create the window in the main process, and close it from the window process, the window process will not think the variable exists.

So it sounds like you need to use [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) to communicate from the render to the main process so that it can close the window for you.

It'd be something like:

```
// renderer
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
ipcRenderer.send('close-signin')

// main
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('close-signin', closeSignInWindow)
```